# uploading a file using WCF in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, filestream

I have created one WCF service that will upload the file. and after using that service I am trying to upload the file I am able to successfully upload the file but there is some issue with the FILESTREAM class.

The moment i clicked the button to upload the file when i checked by debugging the application i get to know that stream object is null. 
I am passing the object of stream class to the WCF method.
**But due to some issue that stream object is getting null.**
due to that null object of stream class, image which is uploded getting empty in my folder

This is my code that I am using to upload the file

```
 if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileTransferServiceReference.ITransferService clientUpload = new FileTransferServiceReference.TransferServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService");
            FileTransferServiceReference.RemoteFileInfo uploadRequestInfo = new RemoteFileInfo();


            string Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FileUpload1.FileName);

            using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(FileUpload1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            {
                uploadRequestInfo.FileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
                uploadRequestInfo.Length = fileInfo.Length;
                uploadRequestInfo.FileByteStream = stream;
                clientUpload.UploadFile(uploadRequestInfo);
            }
        }
```

Code for WCF Service

```
public RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request)
        {
            RemoteFileInfo result = new RemoteFileInfo();
            try
            {
                // get some info about the input file
                string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"c:\Uploadfiles", request.FileName);
                System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);

                // check if exists
                if (!fileInfo.Exists) throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("File not found", request.FileName);

                // open stream
                System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

                // return result

                result.FileName = request.FileName;
                result.Length = fileInfo.Length;
                result.FileByteStream = stream;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return result;

        }


        public void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
        {
            FileStream targetStream = null;
            Stream sourceStream = request.FileByteStream;


            string uploadFolder = @"C:\upload\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);
            }

            string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, request.FileName);

            using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                const int bufferLen = 65000;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
                {
                    targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                targetStream.Close();
                sourceStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't easier to send a byte[]?

Comment: I am bit confused how do i achieve this. can you show me how it will be possible

Comment: first parameter is for the full path in filstream but I am passing only the name of the fill will that be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Spot the difference:

```
 string uploadFolder = @"C:\upload\";

 ...

 string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"c:\Uploadfiles", request.FileName);
```

As a general tip you might put your upload file path into an external configuration file, so that you can change it when you move your application onto a server where you need to store the data on a different drive or in a specific location.

Also that way you are always calling the same configuration entry so your upload path name is definitely going to be the same everywhere.

Comment: uploadfiles is for downloaded images. My main issue is in if (FileUpload1.HasFile)... this code and specifically this 'stream' object is returning null value please check if  using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(FileUpload1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)) has any mistakes

Comment: first parameter is for the full path in filstream but I am passing only the name of the fill will that be the issue

Comment: When you debug the code, what is the value of your filepath and does the file exist at that path?

Comment: Path is returning empty string that is why I am not using that path's value but the first parameter of the filestream is for path of the file so how can i get the full path of the image i suppose i am uploading my image through E drive then is there any way by that i can pass that full path in the first parameter

Comment: Does the file path exist? Is the file being uploaded to `c:\upload\filename` as you would expect?